# Swagger prints only string datatype in Django Rest Framework using DefaultRouter

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm struggling with generating documentation (or simply - with whole project). I'm barely new to Django and Python, so maybe my problem is quite trivial.

I've got bunch of well defined models in Django Rest Framework project, for working with them I'm using DefaultRouters - the project is starting now and is in the early phase of development. However, for have all actions listed, I've managed to install Swagger and run it. My problem is, that Swagger in all actions, in almost all parameters prints "string" data type. For example:

Model

```
class UseCaseVer(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True),
    version_key = models.CharField(max_length=10,null=False,unique=True)
    approv_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now,null=False)
    description = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = False
```

Serializer:

```
class UseCaseVerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
date_joined = serializers.DateTimeField()

class Meta(object):
    model = UseCaseVer
    fields = ('id', 'version_key', 'approv_date', 'description')
```

Still gives me string in all fields. What is wrong?

Comment: "Almost all parameters" - everything except id?

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is wrong. It gives you [json](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). For example in python, to get actual values, you need to use `json.loads()`

Comment: That's true, tested now, but is there any way to force Swagger to print correct data types?

Comment: In short - no. JSON is a usual way to transfer different data structures through http. Maybe, there is some extension in Swagger to parse json. But anyway, you will have to parse it

Comment: Okay, you calmed me down :) Thanks buddy